# handling null parameter in where clause stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a better way in sql to select all if a variable is null and if it's not null apply the where filter?

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrders]  
    @OrderNo varchar(50) =null
    AS

    IF @OrderNo IS NULL
        BEGIN   
            SELECT CustomerNo,Name,Surname,etc...
            FROM Customers 
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN       
            SELECT CustomerNo,Name,Surname,etc...
            FROM Customers 
            WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo
        END
```

tried as follows but does not do it
WHERE (OrderNo IS NULL OR OrderNo = @OrderNo)

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomerNo,Name,Surname,etc...
            FROM Customers 
            WHERE (OrderNo is null and 1=1)
                    Or
                    (OrderNo is not null and OrderNo = @OrderNo)
```

Comment: add "WITH RECOMPILE" and it actually works without serious side effects.

Comment: do you mean add "with recompile to AK47 suggestion?

Comment: yes. Because otherwise the SP picks the query plan based on the first set of parameters it gets. If those are totally off compared to each other, this means you may get stuck with a TERRIBLE query plan. Check http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/ for an in depth explanation.

Comment: TomTom where do place WithRecompile in AK47 suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify the life of the SQL Server query optimizer by creating two stored procedures. One that fetches all and one that fetches by `OrderNo`. That will make the query plan the best possible for the two different scenarios. Your version using `IF` in one procedure might get issues with the queryplan for the query filtered by OrderNo if the plan is created when the parameter is `NULL`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrdersByOrderNo]  
    @OrderNo varchar(50)
AS

SELECT CustomerNo,Name,Surname,etc...
FROM Customers 
WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrders]  
AS

SELECT CustomerNo,Name,Surname,etc...
FROM Customers
```

If you for some reason need one procedure for the client to use you should do a wrapper procedure that in turn calls the procedures above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrders]  
    @OrderNo varchar(50)
AS

IF @OrderNo IS NULL 
  EXEC dbo.GetAllOrders
ELSE
  EXEC dbo.GetOrdersByOrderNo @OrderNo
```